# Are these correct headings for a spreadsheet?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, usage

The spreadsheet is related to food safety (processing, handling, storage, etc.)

ID: 编号 (项目?)
Process: 制程
Food category:食品类别
Standard: 标准
Frequency (as in how many times per day or every how many hours): 次数
Min. Value: 最小(低?) value?
Max. Value: 最大(高?) value?
Food Correction (or Corrective Action): 纠正措施
Check List Item Caption: 清单项目标题
Question Group: 问题组
Template: 模板

Thank you.

Two more I am working on:

Repeat Observation (yes or no question about whether the observation should be repeated or "performed" again): 反复观察 or 一再发生?

Policy (any company policy or standard is entered in this section and applied to that specific question): I think 政策 is only for government/political policy, right? How about 方针, is that the correct translation for a company policy/rule/standard?

Order index (a numeric value assigned to each row that indicates which order category it belongs to such as 1, 2, or 3): does 秩序指数 work for that?

Comment: It looks good. but I would suggest 最少 and 最多 for min and max.

Comment: Thanks. How about for ID, which of my two is better?

Comment: 编号 is good enough

Answer (score 3):

Without complete context I am just going with the most common translations:

- Process 流程
- Frequency 频率
- Check List Item Caption: 清单项标题 (项目 also means 'project' which can be confusing)
- Repeat Observation 是否多次观察到 or 是否多次发生 (是否 makes it explicit that it's a Yes-No question; 多次 is neutral while 一再 has slight derogatory tone but both are fine)
- Policy 政策 (company policy <=> 公司政策 is a common translation. 方针 is more like 'direction; principle'.)
- Order Index: 顺序编号 or 订单编号, depending on whether Order here means sequencing (顺序) or written request (订单). Don't use 秩序指数, it's not understood.

Answer (score 3):

> Repeat Observation (yes or no question about whether the observation
>   repeated or "performed" again): 反复观察 or 一再发生?

复查 is better than 反复观察.

> Policy (any company policy or standard is entered in this section and
>   applied to that specific question): I think 政策 is only for
>   government/political policy, right? How about 方针, is that the correct
>   translation for a company policy/rule/standard?

规章制度 or just use one of 规章 and 制度. 方针 is also used for gov/political policy more.

> Order index (a numeric value assigned to each row that indicates which
>   order category it belongs to such as 1, 2, or 3): does 秩序指数 work for
>   that?

Order used here means 顺序 rather than 秩序, so 排序值 will be you want.

By the way, Chinese like use two-characters word in a spreadsheet's headings.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good. I would translate "frequency" with "频率"

Answer (score 1):

ID: 编号  
Process: 程序  
 
Food category: 食品类别  
Standard: 标准  
Frequency (as in how many times per day or every how many hours): 频率  
Min. Value: 低标   
Max. Value: 高标   
Food Correction (or Corrective Action): 改正措施 
Check List Item Caption: 清单项目标语 (标题 is title)  
Question Group: 问题组  
Template: 模板   
Repeat Observation: 重复观察？  
Policy: 规章制度 
Order index: 订购类别

Answer (score 0):

Process: 制程 sounds strange, maybe 流程 is better (but it depends on the context).